# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied - Running the program in vs code

Tags: python, file, operating-system, shutil

I am trying to write a program for deleting all the temp files on my system. I have using `os module` from `python 3.9.1` and I am running it on `VS Code`. I tried to find out the solution, where it was suggested to run the terminal in `Administrator mode`, but I am using vs code. I found that there are no functions that can allow to change the mode of user.
Below is the code,

```
import os
import shutil

os.chdir('c:\\Windows\\Temp')
for folderNames,subfolderNames,fileNames in os.walk('c:\\Windows\\Temp'):
    print('The folder is '+ folderNames)
    print('The subfolder in '+folderNames+' are: '+str(subfolderNames))
    print('The filenames in '+folderNames+' are:'+str(fileNames))
    print()

    for file in fileNames:
        os.unlink(file)
        #print(file)
    for folder in subfolderNames:
        shutil.rmtree(subfolderNames)
        #print(os.path.join('c:\\Windows\\Temp\\'),folder)
```

It gives me this error : `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'adobegc.log'`

Could you please help...

Thank you
swetha

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the file in administrator mode using `runas` command.

```
runas /user:Administrator your_Command
```

If your command includes spaces, don't forget to add quotes.

```
runas /user:Administrator "your command"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I am trying to run this program in vs code, so how will I be able to write a command? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Run the command on VScode terminal, the command will run with elevated privilege. Assume, you saved your python code in a file called "delete.py". To run this file you need to execute the command, `python delete.py` in the VScode terminal. To run this command in administrator mode, go to VScode terminal and run this command: 
`runas /user:Administrator "python delete.py"`. Hope this clarifies your query.

Comment: Thank you...i'll try this :)